# creating datatemplate from existing control in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, datatemplate

Is there a way to create a `DataTemplate` from existing controls in WPF?
for example, say I have in my resources a Grid the following way:

```
<Grid x:Key="grid" .. />
```

Can I somehow use this grid as the `DataTemplate` for another control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to create a `DataTemplate` containing the grid in a resource dictionary.  To display the `Grid` you could use a `ContentControl` and you could use the `DataTemplate` to template other controls.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="grid">
        <Grid />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - this is exactly the situation I need to avoid, as I have many resources which are currently used as Contents of ContentControl. I'm trying to avoid this massive refactory of resources into datatemplate by finding a way to use those resources as DataTemplates

Comment: @Oren put the data templates in the resources not the actual controls.

Comment: I currently have hundreds of controls defined in many resource files, I want to implement the change in one generic place instead of explicitly refactoring all such resources (that are used as contents of content controls) which can take weeks to finish. I would also like to force with such implementation that this will not reoccur when other developers add new resources.

Comment: A DataTemplate can also be used as the Content for a ContentControl, maybe you just want to wrap all your controls in a DataTemplate thus making them all re-usable.

Comment: I want to avoid wrapping manually all my controls in a DataTemplate. I'm looking for a way to create a DataTemplate from a control's instance so the control will effectively be used as a DataTemplate

Comment: Ok then, when you need to define a new DataTemplate add a ContentControl and reference the control as a static resource.

Comment: But that doesn't help with current usage of resources, I need to change current usage of resources

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11114/discussion-between-slugart-and-oren)